# Extended Glob: What is the difference in syntax between ?(list), *(list), +(list) and @(list)

Tags: bash, wildcards

I have a question after reading about extended glob.

After using `shopt -s extglob`,

What is the difference in the following?

```
?(list): Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns.

*(list): Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns.

+(list): Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.

@(list): Matches one of the given patterns.
```

Yes, I have read the above description that accompanies them, but for practical purpose, I can't see situations where people would prefer ?(list) over *(list). That is, I don't see any difference.

I've tried the following:

```
$ ls
> test1.in test2.in test1.out test2.out`

$ echo *(*.in)
> test1.in test2.in

$ echo ?(*.in)
> test1.in test2.in
```

I'd expect `$ echo ?(*.in)` to output `test1.in` only, from the description, but it does not appear to be the case. Thus, could anyone give an example where it makes a difference regarding the type of extended glob used?

**Source**: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Extended_Globs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls
abbc  abc  ac
$ echo a*(b)c
abbc abc ac
$ echo a+(b)c
abbc abc
$ echo a?(b)c
abc ac
$ echo a@(b)c
abc
```

Answer (score 3):

"One or more occurrence" means one or more within the *same* file name, not one or more file names matching. `foo?(.in).x` matches `foo.in.x` while `foo*(.in).x` should also match `foo.in.in.x`

Comment: `foo?(.in).x` matches `foo.in.x` _and_ `foo.x` (if present).